# AADSTS500082: SAML assertion is not present in the token

Tags: office365, saml-2.0

Getting error when I configured `adfs` with `SAML`  Exception details:

> System.IO.InvalidDataException: ID4250: The ClaimValue cannot be null.

Comment: You have to provide more details. In particular, it seems one of your attributes is empty and cannot be put into a claim. Have you tried to use an http debugger to look at the SAML token? Or, is it adfs that refuses to issue the token?

Comment: My use cases , I have taken ADFS as a IDP and o365 as a service when I m trying to login in O365 it is redirecting to adfs Page then I m entering the username and password but it is not going to to O365 user console only I am getting error in SAML response ""AADSTS500082: SAML assertion is not present in the token. "